# Multidimensional Associative Array, session() and isset() for login, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm trying to create a simple login page,

if I take the following array variant it works:
`$users = [['hello@domain.de' => 'Asd23'], ['hello2@domain.de' => 'hell5123']];`
`if (isset($logins[$userKey][$email]) && $logins[$userKey][$email] == $password)`

but with the following Multidimensional Associative Array variant I can't do it.
**What am I doing or am I getting it wrong?**

```php
// Multidimensional Associative Array
$users = [
  ////////////
  [
    'email' => 'sandra@domain.com',
    'password' => 'San1',
    'name' => 'Sandra',
    'lastname' => 'Meier',
    'status' => 'Admin',
    'content' => ''
  ],
  [
    'email' => 'franz@domain.com',
    'password' => 'Fra1',
    'name' => 'Franz',
    'lastname' => 'Eder',
    'status' => 'Standard',
    'content' => 'leer'
  ],
]

// check and assign submitted email and password to new variable
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

  // find the key from the given email
  // Multidimensional Array Searching (Find key by specific value)
  $userKey = array_search($email, array_column($users, 'email'));

  // check if the given email address and password exist and match
  if (isset($users[$userKey][$email]) && $users[$userKey][$password] == $password) {
    // success: email address and password exist and the email address matches the password

    // set session variables and redirect to protected page
    $_SESSION['UserData']['email'] = $users[$userKey][$email];
    header("location:{$protocol_domain}{$actualURl}");
    exit;
  } else {
    // unsuccessful attempt: email address and password do not exist or the emails do not match

    // Set error message
    $msg = '<span style="color:red">Invalid Login Details</span>';
  }

}
```

Comment: What errors or unexpected behaviour do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching with `$userKey = array_search($email, array_column($users, 'email'));` will give you **index**, e.g. - `0`.

Next you check if `$users[0][$email]` is set. But it is **not** set, because you don't have key `$email`, you have key `'email'` (a plain string), same for `$password`/`'password'`, so check should be:

```
// you check that 
// - 'email' key is set and 
// - value in 'password' key is same as value from $_POST
if (isset($users[$userKey]['email']) && $users[$userKey]['password'] == $password) {
```

Also update your session set as:

```
$_SESSION['UserData']['email'] = $users[$userKey]['email'];
```

Comment: thanks,I have now used the strings, I do not receive an error message, but I am not logged in either. what else could be wrong? the session is correctly defined?

Comment: I suppose it should be `$_SESSION['UserData']['email'] = $users[$userKey]['email'];`, no? For the same reason as previous changes.